# Getting SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. Error code 0x80004005 on Sybase DB to File Extraction

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am getting data from Sybase DB (using ODBC Connection) to load into the file using MS-SSIS but in the data flow task while getting from the source its giving the following errors.

> :Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED. The
> PrimeOutput method on  returned error code 0x80004005.
> The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called
> PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the
> component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.
> There may be error messages posted before this with more information
> about the failure.

I have tried with setting MaxConCurrentExecutions=1 as suggested on some web pages as well.

Using the same connection/same DB is working fine for some instances of Table extraction.
The same extraction works totally fine while running on the Debug mode using MS-Visual Studio SSDT.

This error is only showing up while running through MS-SQL Server Job Agent

I need help to solve this issue. Any help would be appreciated.